# Storing objects in an Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I'm working with a database, and trying to store the rows of a table as dictionary in an Array.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "ProgettoAppDelegate.h"
#import "AddItemViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize nibLoadedCell;
@synthesize addItem;

NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
NSMutableArray *shoppingListItems; <--i created here...
NSDictionary *editItem;

-(void) loadDataFromDb {
//apriamo il database
sqlite3 *db;
int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)

ProgettoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProgettoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
if (dbrc) {
    NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
    return;
}
//database aperto! Prendiamo i valori dal database.
sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database
NSString *queryStatementNS = @"select key, item, price, groupid, dateadded from shoppinglist order by item";
const char *queryStatement = [queryStatementNS UTF8String];
dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);

//Richiamo la funzione sqlite3_step() finché ho righe nel database
while ((dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    int primaryKeyValueI = sqlite3_column_int(dbps, 0);
    NSNumber *primaryKeyValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:primaryKeyValueI];
    NSString *itemValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char*) sqlite3_column_text(dbps, 1)];
    double priceValueD = sqlite3_column_double(dbps, 2);
    NSNumber *priceValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:priceValueD];
    int groupValueI = sqlite3_column_int(dbps, 3);
    NSNumber *groupValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:groupValueI];
    NSString *dateValueS = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char*) sqlite3_column_text(dbps, 4)];
    NSDate *dateValue = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateValueS];

    NSMutableDictionary *rowDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    [rowDict setObject:primaryKeyValue forKey: ID_KEY];
    [rowDict setObject:itemValue forKey: ITEM_KEY];
    [rowDict setObject:priceValue forKey: PRICE_KEY];
    [rowDict setObject:groupValue forKey: GROUP_ID_KEY];
    [rowDict setObject:dateValue forKey: DATE_ADDED_KEY];

    [shoppingListItems addObject: rowDict];
    NSLog(@"%d", [shoppingListItems count]); //I have a Breakpoint here!

    //rilascio tutti gli elementi
    [dateValue release];
    [primaryKeyValue release];
    [itemValue release];
    [priceValue release];
    [groupValue release];
    [rowDict release];
}
}
```

using Breakpoint at the end of the procedure, i can see that in the variables there are the contents of the database, but array "shoppingListItems" is empty. (count = 0)

If you are brave enough to take a look, here there is the entire project: http://cl.ly/9uvb

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not affecting count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count) and [NSMutableArray addObject: not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare all your variables as instance variables, i mean in the .h file as shown below

```
// .h
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    UITableViewCell *nibLoadedCell;
    AddItemViewController *addItem;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

    NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    NSMutableArray *shoppingListItems; // <--- this is only a declaration (not creates the object)
    NSDictionary *editItem;
}
```

And correctly initialize the objects, viewDidLoad is a good place to do this work:

//.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    shoppingListItems = [NSMutableArray new]; // <---- This create the object
    // other initialization ....

    if (!dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    }

    if (! priceFormatter) {
        priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    }
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Your problem resides on a nil value for `shoppingListItems` also dont forget to release the variable on your `dealloc` method

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown the definition of shoppingListItems but there are two common problems when adding to an array:

1. The array is an NSArray and not a NSMutableArray as it must be
2. The array is nil - you may have created it using [NSMutableArray array] without explicit retain?

Yeah, checked your code - you never initialise it at all. Fix that and you should be OK.

Comment: It's mutable, I created as `NSMutableArray *shoppingListItems;`

Comment: You defined it, but didn't create it. Until you assign something to that pointer (like shoppingListItems = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]) it is nil and addObject, as a message to nil, will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your code above that creates the array.  If `shoppingListItems` is nil, then those `-addObject:` messages do nothing.

Comment: The array is a NSMutableArray created on top `#include <sqlite3.h>

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize nibLoadedCell;
@synthesize addItem;

NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
NSMutableArray *shoppingListItems;`...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't ever actually creating the array to go in `shoppingListItems`, so it's nil.

Comment: I created! And i used this code in another project that do the same thing, but in the other one is working fine, here I have this strange problem...