# Array count is 0 directly after calling addObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Why is the count of otherArray 0 even though self.array has N items and the for loop is executing N times?

```
for (MyObject *obj in self.array) 
{
    [self.otherArray addObject:obj];
    NSLog(@"Num items: %d", [self.otherArray count]);
}
```

self.otherArray is an NSMutableArray*

LATER: Doh!, forgot to call alloc/init (I come from a language where the equivalent of addObejct will create the array if necessary).

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not affecting count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count) and [NSMutableArray addObject: not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the most common reason this would occur is if self.otherArray isn't initialized.  If you add a check to self.otherArray, I would suspect it is nil.  If you added:

```
self.otherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

right before the other code, I suspect it would work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess: You have not initialized `self.otherArray` correctly.

Second best guess: `self.otherArray` is not mutable.

Test this by posting your initialization code.

Comment: Doh, didn't call alloc/init (I've come from a language where the equivalent of calling addObject will also create the array if necessary.)

Comment: @Mungbeans You are not alone in this mistake. Let me know if that doesn't fix the issue.