# Why doesn't my datasource property get set?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties

I have a `UITableView` whose controller looks like this:

```
@interface FLWorkspaceViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* workspaces;

@end
```

I try to set that array in another controller:

```
for(NSDictionary* workspace in workspaces)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",workspace);
            [workspaceViewController.workspaces addObject:workspace];
        }

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:workspaceViewController animated:YES];
```

I've checked the values and they exist. When I count `workspaces` in `viewDidLoad`, it's 0. Why is this?

Comment: make sure you have allocated memory to your workspaces array...

Comment: please check that workspaceViewController & workspaceViewController.workspaces is not nil

Comment: where/when should i alloc the workspaces array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar), [NSMutableArray addObject: not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count), [NSMutableArray addObject: not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@property` statements create the pointers for you, but not the actual content. Since I don't see it in your code: Do you `alloc init` your `NSMutableArray *workspaces` somewhere?

EDIT: Probably the best way to initialise your `workspaces` array would be in a getter method in the class where you define the `@property`. Lazy initialisation is preferrable. Best amend your `@synthesize` statement to read something like `@synthesize workspaces = i_workspaces;`, then you can write your getter like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)workspaces {
    if (i_workspaces == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *i_workspaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    }
    return i_workspaces;
}
```

The capacity statement just helps the compiler optimise, it doesn't have to be exact.

Comment: you mean my NSMutableArray correct? I don't alloc init it anywhere. Should I do it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Probably the most solid solution would be to write a lazy-initialisation getter in `FLWorkspaceViewController`. I'll amend my answer in a second...