# Object remains null after set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to set the properties of an object, but it remains null. Can anyone tell me why, please?

Declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ListItem *listItem
```

Here's the code:

```
NSLog(@"Selected: %@", [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
[listItem setCategory:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
NSLog(@"set %@", listItem);
```

and the output:

```
2012-06-28 14:47:43.037 MarketList[10508:fb03] Selected: <Category: 0xb72a9e0> (entity: Category; id: 0xb7252e0 <x-coredata://F9BFC1DF-1D80-477E-9BC6-3C0949AD922F/Category/p2> ; data: {
listItem = "<relationship fault: 0x6d29930 'listItem'>";
name = "Teste 2";})
2012-06-28 14:47:43.038 MarketList[10508:fb03] set (null)
```

Comment: Are you ever creating `listItem`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `listItem` holds `nil`, not an instance of ListItem. You never actually point it to an instance of ListItem, so it's still `nil` at the end of your method. Sending a message to `nil` does not cause an object to magically spring into existence to receive the message — `nil` just silently swallows it. You have to create your ListItem first and *then* set its property.

Comment: Of course --'
I changed the variable that was using and forgot to create it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. there is a semicolon missing in your property declaration (assuming this is just a typo though).
2. Do you ever actually initialize the ListItem? (ie `listItem = [[ListItem alloc] init];`
   If you don't, the pointer to it will be nil, and would cause exactly this behavior (calls with a nil pointer are just ignored).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Selected: %@", [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
listItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[listItem setCategory:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
NSLog(@"set %@", listItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just alloc the object before using it. Alloc it in viewDidLoad.