# can't figure out why NSMutableArray addObject is not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSMutableArray addObject not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working)

I have a NSMutableArray declared as (nonatomic,retain) in my .h file, and properly synthesized. tempRandomWord is an NSString that is always populated.However,count is always returning 0. Any ideas why?

```
[pastWords addObject:tempRandomWord];
int count=[pastWords count];
NSLog(@"%i",count);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working), [NSMutableArray addObject: not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count), [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar).

Comment: did you allocate `pastWords` anywhere? ie: `pastWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: You should be `NSLog`-ing `tempRandomWord` also.

Comment: @Dan F- I did not, but I was under the impression that if I used ARC, that this is unnecessary for declared properties. I have other NSMutableArrays declared in the same way, without explicitly written allocation or initialization, that are working fine

Comment: @Dustin- I do, I just left it out of this question. It always comes up with a word

Comment: @user1418214 all arrays must be allocated and initialized in some way, ARC is irrelevant in that respect.  All ARC does is you do not have to `retain` and `release` the properties manually.  You must be assigning those other arrays to preconstructed arrays somehow.

Comment: @DanF- that was it thanks! But how could I have gotten away with not allocating and initializing my other arrays that are being used without flaw?

Comment: @user1418214 It entirely depends on how you were assigning those arrays, without looking at more of your code, I cannot provide much of a better explanation

Comment: If you don't allocate it, the variable supposed to hold the array will most likely be nil. Sending the message addObject: to nil will be ignored, and sending the message count will return 0. Sending messages to nil doesn't raise an exception, unlike calling methods on NULL in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is not initialized.
just add a lazy initialization somewhere before you read/use the property.

```
self.pastWords=self.pastWords?self.pastWords:[NSMutableArray array];
```

or if you use iVars directly:

```
pastWords=pastWords?pastWords:[NSMutableArray new];
```

or normal initialization in init

If you assign that property from outside of the class you may want to call mutableCopy to make sure the mutable array is used, even if NSArray is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to initialize your array. You need this line in your viewDidLoad or somewhere else

```
pastWords = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I personally like to put them where they're needed like so:

```
if (!pastWords) {
    pastWords = [NSMutableArray array];
}

[pastwords addObject:object];
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that clearly have duplicates indicated in the comments; instead, post your answer on the original.